# How to group and apply custom aggregation function to get mode values of a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the mode value of X variable, and maximum value of Y variable, grouped by (ID, Date), with two conditions:

(1) If there are zeros and other values in X for same (ID, Date), don't consider the zeros, and if there only zeros, so the mode value suppose to be 0.

(2) If there are two mode values in X for same (ID, Date), take the earlier one in terms of time.

Data illustraion:

```
ID  Date        Time    Y       X
1   08/27/2019  18:00   0       123
1   08/27/2019  19:00   0       123
1   08/27/2019  20:00   1       456
2   08/26/2019  18:00   0       0
2   08/26/2019  19:00   0       0
2   08/26/2019  20:00   1       456
3   08/27/2019  18:00   1       123
3   08/27/2019  19:00   0       0
3   08/27/2019  20:00   1       456
3   08/28/2019  18:00   0       0
3   08/28/2019  19:00   0       0
3   08/28/2019  20:00   0       0
4   08/28/2019  18:00   1       123
4   08/28/2019  19:00   1       789
4   08/28/2019  20:00   1       789
```

Expected result:

```
ID  Date        Y       X
1   08/27/2019  1       123
2   08/26/2019  1       456
3   08/27/2019  1       123
3   08/28/2019  0       0
4   08/28/2019  1       789
```

For now, I've used this:

```
df = (df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'Y':'max', 'X': lambda x: x.mode()}))
```

Comment: What's the problem here @qwerty

Comment: Look at the two conditions that I've mentioned...

Comment: are you sure your expected output is correct or can you try : `(df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg({'Y':'max', 'X': lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]}))` ?

Comment: What is the importance of (2) if you already group by date, and you don't want the time in your expected output?

Comment: I don't want the time, but it's necessary to determine the X value if there are multiple mode values.

Comment: @anky_91 My expected output is correct. If there zero values, and other values, we shouldn't consider the zero values.

Comment: @qwerty so the second row of expected output shoule be `08/26/2019  1  456`??

Comment: @anky_91 Yes. Also, I've added three more rows at the end and updated the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first sort the values according to time.

```py
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Date', 'Time'],ascending=True)
```

Then, you can apply a custom aggregation function with your defined 2 conditions on `X` column.

```py
def custom_agg_func(x):
    x = x[x > 0] #Filter out all zero values from X

    #If there are no values then return 0 as mode else first value from sorted list
    return 0 if x.size < 1 else x.mode().iloc[0]


result_df = (df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'Y':'max', 'X': custom_agg_func}))

print(result_df)
```

Outputs:

```
   ID        Date  Y    X
0   1  08/27/2019  1  123
1   2  08/26/2019  1  456
2   3  08/27/2019  1  123
3   3  08/28/2019  0    0
4   4  08/28/2019  1  789
```

Comment: a custom aggregation is what you want here. +1