# How to get the folder name from path string and add it to a new column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, tar

I want to read folders' names from tar.gz file, and create column that contains the names.

I'm using this code:

```
file_path = r"C:\Users\filename.tar.gz"
start_with = './mainfolder/'

import tarfile
import re
with tarfile.open(file_path, "r:*") as tar:
    csv_path = tar.getnames()
    csv_path = list(n for n in tar.getnames() if (n.endswith('.csv')) & (n.startswith(start_with)))
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    csv_list = []

    for file in csv_path:
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(tar.extractfile(file))
        csv_list.append(df_temp)

    df = pd.concat(csv_list)
```

In the main folder there are few folders that have names.
After reading a csv file from folder "X" (for example), "FolderName" column should be created in this csv file and has to contain the name of the folder ("X") for all the rows.
And so for every csv file.

An exmaple for path string: `./mainfolder/1001_name` or `./mainfolder/1002_some_name`

Comment: Whats the issue with your current code? any errors?

Comment: It's just reading the csv files and concatenating them. But I want to add the folder name (which the file comes from) as a column.

Comment: I've added a solution in the answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the following line:

```py
df_temp = pd.read_csv(tar.extractfile(file))
```

You can get the folder name from `file` path string using `os.path.dirname()` method. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372054/get-folder-name-of-the-file-in-python).

You'll need to `import os` module.

Example:

```py
#returns ./mainfolder/1001_name
full_folder_path = os.path.dirname(file)

#returns 1001_name
folder = os.path.basename(full_folder_path)

#returns name bit
result = folder[folder.index('_')+1:]

df_temp['FolderName'] = result
```

This create a new column called `FolderName` and set the value for all rows. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039023/add-column-with-constant-value-to-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: @qwerty, you can split the value by `_` and keep the last bit :)

Comment: @qwerty, just posted a possible answer for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673386/aggregate-by-id-and-date-and-get-maximum-and-mode-values-for-specified-columns/58684885#58684885